# flutter riverpod how to return multiple types from one provider

Tags: flutter, riverpod, freezed

I am using riverpod , I created a StateNotifierProvider like this:

```
final mainUserProvider = StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose<
    MainUserController, AsyncValue<dynamic>>((ref) {
  return MainUserController(ref);
});
```

and this is my controller :

```
class MainUserController extends StateNotifier<AsyncValue<dynamic>> {
  MainUserController(this.ref)
      : super(const AsyncValue.loading());

  final Ref ref;

  Future<void> getAllUsers() async {
    // state = const UIState.loading();
    final result = get all users;

    state = AsyncValue.data(result);
  }
}
```

Now In ui I am using like this:

```
class UserExploreScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {

 var mainUserState = ref.watch(mainUserProvider);
....
            mainUserState.whenOrNull(
              data: (mainProductCategories) {
                return GridView(
                  gridDelegate: ResponsiveGridDelegate(
                       ....
                  ),
                  primary: false,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: mainProductCategories.map(
                    (user) {
                      return UsersCard(
                        isSelected: false,
                        title: user.name,
                        imageUrl: user. Icon ?? "",
                         .....
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  ).toList(),
                );
              },
              loading: () => Container(),
            )!,
```

but I am getting this error :

```
Expected a value of type 'List<Widget>', but got one of type 'List<dynamic>'
```

I guess because in provider I did not mention the type, and I dont want mention, because I need to return other type of object, Now list of user and later other type like Production .

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `dynamic` it means you're disabling static checking. If you want to have an object that serve more than one type, consider using the `Object` type instead.

Take the following example:

```dart
dynamic firstList = [2,4];
List<Object> secondList = [2,4];
final a = firstList.map((e) => Container()).toList();
final b = secondList.map((e) => Container()).toList();
```

`a` is a `dynamic`, while `b` is a `List<Container>` (which is expected).

---

These should be a good read:

- [AVOID using dynamic unless you want to disable static checking](https://dart.dev/effective-dart/design#avoid-using-dynamic-unless-you-want-to-disable-static-checking)
- [The Dart type system](https://dart.dev/language/type-system)

Comment: because I have to create a lot of classes for each request. It is not good, I come from Bloc and getx , we can return any type from one bloc or a controller. there is no way to do that?